# COUNT WITH 2 CONDITIONS IN ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I was trying so hard to make a query from 1 table with 2 conditions.
And every condition should be able to count the row based on transaction date.

QUERY 1:

```sql
SELECT 
  INST_NO,
  TRUNC(INS_TS)INS_TS,
  COUNT(*) TOTAL_INSPECTION
FROM TMCI_QC_LINE2
WHERE INST_NO='M190200772'
GROUP BY 
    INST_NO, 
    TRUNC(INS_TS)
```

RESULT OF QUERY 1:

```
INST_NO      INS_TS      TOTAL_INSPECTION
M190200772   18-FEB-19         8 
M190200772   19-FEB-19         3
```

QUERY 2:

```sql
SELECT 
  INST_NO,
  TRUNC(INS_TS)INS_TS,
  COUNT(*) CASE_INSPECTION
FROM TMCI_QC_LINE2 
WHERE INST_NO='M190200772' AND QTY_OK IN (0)
GROUP BY
    INST_NO,
    TRUNC(INS_TS)
```

RESULT OF QUERY 2:
Table 2:

```
INST_NO      INS_TS      CASE_INSPECTION
M190200772   18-FEB-19          4 
M190200772   19-FEB-19          2
```

Now, I would like the results to look like this:

```
INST_NO      INS_TS      INSPECTION    CASE
M190200772   18-FEB-19       8           4
M190200772   19-FEB-19       3           2
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the 1st query and conditional aggregation for the new column:

```
SELECT 
  INST_NO,
  TRUNC(INS_TS) INS_TS, 
  COUNT(*) INSPECTION,
  SUM(CASE WHEN QTY_OK = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) CASE
FROM TMCI_QC_LINE2
WHERE INST_NO='M190200772'
GROUP BY INST_NO, TRUNC(INS_TS)
```

Comment: Personally, I think I'd use `count(case when qty_ok = 0 then 1 end) case_inspection`, as 1) it's shorter and 2) it's clearer that you're doing a count. But either one would work

Comment: For me summing 1s with explicitly setting 0s in the else part is always more readable, but it's a matter of style too.

Comment: Yup; just offering an alternative for the OP *{:-)

Comment: Thank you very much its really works, both of it is running well in my query :)